# After make install via cmake - grpc forlders is empty

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc, oraclelinux

I try to installing GRPC from sources.
I have Oracle Linux 7.9, GCC 10.2.1 from devtoolset-10 and cmake version 3.21.0-rc1 built from sources.

The way i used:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.37.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
cd grpc
 mkdir -p cmake/build
 pushd cmake/build
 cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON \
      -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$/usr/local/bin \
      ../.. 
make
make install
```

After this i see that files from /root/grpc/cmake/build$/usr/local/bin/lib/....files been created in /usr/local/....

Ok. But when i change directory to /usr/local - this directory does`t content files from make install.

What i doing wrong?

BTW, when i try to built 1.38 version of GRPS i return building error:

```
/root/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc: In function ‘void gpr_default_log(gpr_log_func_args*)’:
/root/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc:97:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘StrFormat(const char [22], const char*, char [64], int32_t&, long int&, const char*&, int&)’
       time_buffer, now.tv_nsec, tid, display_file, args->line);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing clear repro steps. I'll take a look and see if I can get the same result. Note that `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$/usr/local/bin` is off. It should almost certainly be `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```console
$ git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.37.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
$ cmake -G Ninja -S grpc/ -B grpc-build  \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release           \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local    \
    -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON                    \
    -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF
$ cmake --build grpc-build --target install
```

The relevant differences here are that my install prefix doesn't have a stray `$` in it and that I set the build type (which you must always do).

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using CMake 3.20.5 (the latest release) and GCC 10.3.0. Please try the above commands and see if anything changes.